# Powershell: does a file name contain a value

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to check if a filename contains a value that I get from 2 excel Columns (ContractNumber & PONumber). My Script is too slow right now. It has been running for 1 hour, and it completed only 2%.

The files are in 600+ folders within the main directory(shared drive). There are 19K files(pdf/docx). And 40K numbers to check.

How can I improve my script, so it won't take this long to run?

```
#create excel
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\X\Documents\XYZ.xlsx")


# Select the sheet
$sheetContractData = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Contracts")
$sheetCustomerNames = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Customers")
$sheetContractStatus = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Status")


# Amount of row -> TOTAL = 19469
$rowMax = ($sheetContracts.UsedRange.Rows).count


# declare the starting position for each column
$rowContractNumber,$colContractNumber = 2,1
$rowType,$colType = 2,2
$rowCompany,$colCompany = 2,3
$rowStartDate,$colStartDate = 2,4
$rowEndDate,$colEndDate = 2,5
$rowDescription,$colDescription = 2,6
$rowPONumber,$colPONumber = 2,7
$rowContactPerson,$colContactPerson = 2,8
$rowCustomerNumber,$colCustomerNumber = 2,9
$Contracts = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]


# Contract class
class Contract {
    [string]$ContractNumber
    [string]$Type
    [string]$Company
    [string]$StartDate
    [string]$EndDate
    [string]$Description
    [string]$PONumber
    [string]$ContactPerson
    [string]$CustomerNumber
}


# Adding contracts to list
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
    $objContract = [Contract]::new()

    $objContract.ContractNumber = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowContractNumber+$i,$colContractNumber).text
    $objContract.Type = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowType+$i,$colType).text
    $objContract.Company = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowCompany+$i,$colCompany).text
    $objContract.StartDate = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowStartDate+$i,$colStartDate).text
    $objContract.EndDate = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowEndDate+$i,$colEndDate).text
    $objContract.Description = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowDescription+$i,$colDescription).text
    $objContract.PONumber = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowPONumber+$i,$colPONumber).text
    $objContract.ContactPerson = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowContactPerson+$i,$colContactPerson).text
    $objContract.CustomerNumber = $sheetContractData.Cells.Item($rowCustomerNumber+$i,$colCustomerNumber).text

    $Contracts.Add($objContract)

    $prcntComplete = [math]::Round(($i / ($rowMax-1)) * 100 )
    Write-Progress -Activity "Adding contracts to List" -Status "$prcntComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $prcntComplete;
}


# close Excel
$objExcel.quit() 


# Compare all files -> TOTAL = 23265
$totalFilesInDrive = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\X" -Recurse| where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }).count


# Compare files with excel data
$foundContracts = 0
$filesDone = 0

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\X" -Recurse| where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }){
   for ($j=0; $j -le $Contracts.Count-1; $j++)
    {
        Try {
            if($Contracts[$j].ContractNumber.Length -gt 5 -and $file.Name -match '^.*' + $Contracts[$j].ContractNumber + '.*\.(([pP][dD][fF])|([dD][oO][cC][xX]?))$'){
                $foundContracts += 1
                Break
            }
            elseif($Contracts[$j].PONumber.Length -gt 5 -and $file.Name -match '^.*' + $Contracts[$j].PONumber + '.*\.(([pP][dD][fF])|([dD][oO][cC][xX]?))$'){
                $foundContracts += 1
                Break
            }
        }
        Catch {
            $_ | Out-File C:\Users\X\Desktop\errors.txt -Append
        }
    }

    $progressSearch = [math]::Round(($filesDone / $totalFilesInDrive) * 100, 4)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Searching for contracts with Contractnumber or PO number FULL" -Status "$progressSearch % Complete:" -PercentComplete $progressSearch;

    $filesDone += 1
}

"Contracts Found: " + $foundContracts


# Ratio

Write-Host("{0} % of the contracts can be moved" -f [math]::Round(($foundContracts / $totalFilesInDrive) * 100, 4))
```

Comment: Can you add sample `.pdf` and `.docx` file names so that we could test possible alternatives? Also please add full code (right now `$totalFilesInDrive` seems to be magic)

Comment: I have added the full code (There is some sensitive data so I removed specific paths & names but provided the results). Thanks for trying to to help.

Comment: Generate a single regexp from all ContractNumber and all PONumber when you read the excel file so it looks like `'(111|222|333)\.(pdf|docx?)'` where 111, 222, 333 are these numbers. Then instead of the `for` loop over $Contracts you'll simply do a single `-match`, also note it's already case-insensitive so no need for `[dD][oO][cC][xX]`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the info. But a single regex is not possible because al numbers are different (some are 4, 8, 12 numbers and some have chars at random places). And thanks for the case case-insensitive tip. I will update my code.

Comment: It's possible, the amount of digits doesn't matter, here's an example  '(8751a-8|BB6176#21|FF1200-00)\.(pdf|docx?)$' you will only have to escape the special characters like e.g. $rx += ($ContractNumber -replace `'[.()[\]{}+]','\$&'`) + '|' (and then you'll remove the last `|` of course and add `)\.(pdf|docx?)$`)

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand better what you mean, but then I need to write al the 40K numbers in the regexp? I can do that, that's no problem but it will be a very long string.